# Handle one WP_Query with multidimensional arguments for several loops in Wordpress?

Tags: loops, wordpress

I want to optimize my code down below. locations and dance -styles are both categorycourses, but are identified by contants townLocation1 and TownLocation2
(the ones which isn't locations are dance-styles and vice versa)

```
$locations = get_terms("categorycourses", array('include' => array(townLocation1, townLocation2)));                  
$dance_styles = get_terms("categorycourses", array('exclude' => array(townLocation1, townLocation2))); 

$content = '';

foreach ( $locations as $location ) {                                           
    $content .= . '<h1>'.$location->name.'</h1>';

    foreach ( $dance_styles as $dance_style ) {

        //Show courses that is associated with this dance-style
        //and in this location
        $loop = get_loop_courses($dance_style, $location->term_id); 

        if($loop->have_posts()) {   
        //show courses here (post with custom post type course)
        }

    } //end dance_styles
} //end locations


function get_loop_courses($categorycourse, $location_id) {
    $terms_slug = strtolower($categorycourse->slug);
    $terms_slug = str_replace(' ','', $terms_slug);

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //Show ALL coures (no limit)
        'post_type' => 'course',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'categorycourses',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $terms_slug
            ),
        ),
     );  

    $args['tax_query'][] =  array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'categorycourses',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => array($location_id) 
                    ); 
    }

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    return $loop;
}
```

The `get_loop_courses` get called very many times and therefore when the database grows it's taking a lot of (unnessecary) time to load. My approach was thinking of building up an array of arguments (from the get_loop_courses-function) and then to execute the WP_Query ONCE and loop the resultset in a managable way.  **This is what I've tried:**

```
$locations = get_terms("categorycourses", array('include' => array(townLocation1, townLocation2)));                  
$dance_styles = get_terms("categorycourses", array('exclude' => array(townLocation1, townLocation2))); 

$loop_arr = array();
$content = '';

foreach ( $locations as $location ) {                                           
    $content .= . '<h1>'.$location->name.'</h1>';

    foreach ( $dance_styles as $dance_style ) {

        //Show courses that is associated with this dance-style
        //and in this location
        $loop_arr[] = get_loop_courses($dance_style, $location->term_id); 

    } //end dance_styles
} //end locations

 $loop = new WP_Query($loop_arr); //this is giving me an array but with a lot of posts, and not the ones I intended


function get_loop_courses($categorycourse, $location_id) {
    $terms_slug = strtolower($categorycourse->slug);
    $terms_slug = str_replace(' ','', $terms_slug);

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //Show ALL coures (no limit)
        'post_type' => 'course',
        'no_found_rows' => true, //no pagination!
        'tax_query' => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categorycourses',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $terms_slug
        ),
     ),
     );  

     $args['tax_query'][] =  array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'categorycourses',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array($location_id) 
                ); 
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Am I thinking in "right" direction? Please give me pointers! This approach might not even be possible?

Is it possible to use transient in this case?

Comment: Might be a stupid thing to say, but what happens if you do WP_Query($loop_arr['tax_query']) ?

Comment: @Voltlight - why would that help? That's just a part of the arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The plan:

If we try to plan for the database growth, we might come up with a *display schema* like this one:

[image: Schema]

where:

- It looks like your current solution is suitable for only few posts and terms (yellow)
- With many posts and few terms, we want posts pagination (orange).
- With many terms and few posts, we want to use terms pagination (green).
- For many posts and terms, we want both kind of paginations (blue)

For a scalable taxonomy search solution, we should look for a way to run `WP_Query()` only once for each search query.

### Taxonomy structure:

It looks like you're splitting up your custom `categorycourses` taxonomy into two mutually exclusive parts: *locations* and *dance styles*.

But I would recommend using two custom taxonomies: `locations` and `dancestyle`.

That sounds more logical.

### Native taxonomy search:

When you got a large number of posts, you could use the *native* taxonomy search, to display all posts corresponding to a given location and dance style, for example.

```
example.com/?location=london&dancestyle=tango
```

This will use the *main query* and no need for secondary queries. The *Twenty Twelve* theme will use the `archive.php` template to display the results and you will get the pagination for free!

If we want to use a custom template file instead of `archive.php`, we can modify it with the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter.

### The User Interface:

There are many ways to cook up a user interface for the taxonomy search.

You could consider using a faceted search UI. Check for example this great plugin for good ideas:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/screenshots/

and here's a list of similar plugins:

https://github.com/scribu/wp-query-multiple-taxonomies/wiki/Similar-plugins

### Terms Pagination:

For a large number of terms (thousands), we can consider term pagination or some kind of drill down solutions like A-Z directory listing.

We can setup terms paginations in `get_terms()` by using:

```
get_terms( 'mytaxonomy', 
    array(
        'offset' => $offset,
        'number' => $number,
     )
);
```

I hope this helps you along the way.

Comment: I dont want pagination (or actually the customer dont want that), but it's true that it woud be more logical to divide dance styles and locations into separate taxnomies. I've partially solved the issue by using fragment caching with transients, but first time it takes a long time to load. I was merely looking for a way to optimize the handling of the call to get_loop_courses() (it must be a better way!?) +1 for giving solutions/details!

Comment: It looks like your customer doesn't want a scalable solution, so you it looks like your'e already dealing with it through caching ;-) The problem with fetching everything from a single `WP_Query()` is that it doesn't support taxonomy/term ordering. [Here's one interesting trick](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3715/26350) on how you can fetch all posts within a single taxonomy, with a single query.  You could also write manual SQL queries, but that could be less flexible.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld (sjoe, just getting tired of typing your name :-)) don't forget to award the bounty before it expires. :-)